# How to count the total digit/numbers, the odd numbers and even numbers respectively in a php loop

Tags: php, html, loops, count

I want to count the total numbers in the pyramid loop and I want to count all the odd and even numbers respectively.
There is a problem in my code where odd and even numbers are incorrectly counted.

The result should be:

> Total numbers:

> Total odd numbers:

> Total Even numbers:

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['btnsend'])) {
$oddCount = 0;
$evenCount = 0;

$num = $_POST['number'];
$width = strlen($_POST['number']) + 1;
for ($row = 1; $row <= $num; $row++) {
    if ($ % 2 == 0) 
        $evenCount++;
    else
        $oddCount++;
    echo "<div style='display: flex; justify-content: center; text-align: center;'>";
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $row; $x++) {
        echo "<div style='width: {$width}ch; background: green;'>$row&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}


echo "<p>You have {$evenCount} even and {$oddCount} odd numbers</p>";
```

}

Comment: I'll delete my previous comments, you can do the same. There's a syntax error in your code: `if ($ % 2 == 0)` should be `if ($row % 2 == 0)`.

Comment: I tried putting $row but it only counts the row (if its odd or even) as one.
for example: 1 1 1 1 1 is counted as 1 odd number not 5 odd numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have been able to work this out yourself. It is not a difficult problem. Learning to program is learning to solve problems. If you keep asking other people to solve your problems, you're not learning yourself.

That being said, I think what you want is this:

```
<?php

$userInput = 5;
$oddCount  = 0;
$evenCount = 0;

$num = $userInput;
$width = strlen($num) + 1;
for ($row = 1; $row <= $num; $row++) {
    if ($row % 2 == 0) {
        $evenCount += $row;
    } else {
        $oddCount += $row;
    }    
    echo "<div style='display: flex; justify-content: center; text-align: center;'>";
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $row; $x++) {
        echo "<div style='width: {$width}ch; background: green;'>$row&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}

echo "<p>You have {$evenCount} even and {$oddCount} odd numbers</p>";
```

I had to remove the `$_POST` because I don't have your form. For the input of `5` this returns:

```
You have 6 even and 9 odd numbers
```

Change the input to `10` and you get:

```
You have 30 even and 25 odd numbers
```

As you can see it's not difficult to do.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware As mentioned before, it was a miss assumption. I deleted my comment and upvoted your solution. :)

Comment: @JustKroosing Could you mark the solution from KIKO-Software as ACCEPTED please, if it solves your problem?